# Почему не работает задержка в одну секунду?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace prog1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async void Main()
        {
            string text = "abc123";
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
                Console.Write(text[i]);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Хочу, чтобы буквы строки выводились поочередно с задержкой в одну секунду, но Thread.Sleep(1000) не работает. Почему это происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: abc123 выводится моментально, хотя каждая буква должна выводится с задержкой 1 секунда

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что C# - это не питон. Кодовый блок здесь выделяется не отступами слева, а фигурными скобками.

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write(text[i]);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Еще уберите `async` у `Main`, он здесь вам вообще ни к чему, ну или `async Task` надо вместо `void`, если вы вдруг решили использовать `await`.

Comment: Аааай, точно, спасибо :)